# Count Distinct records based on Class Group and should not have duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Data. I am trying to get a Distinct Count per SR_NUM, per ClassGroup column value being 'Building'. Likewise, when I do count on SR_NUM, per ClassGroup column value being 'Trade', this SR number shouldn't show up as it has already been counted once for 'Building'. I did try by using Not Exists, but it eliminates any count for ClassGroup value 'Trade'.

[image]

Goal/ Desired Result

- I need Distinct Count on ClassGroup value 'Building and 'Trade'. If there is a SR_NUM for 'Building' and 'Trade' class, I need count only for 'building' class and need a separate count for 'trade' class and it should not consider the counts done for the building class. Hope my explanation makes sense.

SQL code I used for this

```
select a.TRANSACTION_TYPE, a.NAME,COUNT(a.SR_NUM), a.CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD, a.ClassGroup (select DISTINCT TRANSACTION_TYPE, NAME,SR_NUM,CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD, ClassGroup From TABLE A )a where NOT Exists(select DISTINCT TRANSACTION_TYPE, NAME,SR_NUM,CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD, ClassGroup From TABLE b WHERE ClassGroup = 'Trade' a.NAME = b.NAME AND a.CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD = b.CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD AND a.TRANSACTION_TYPE = b.TRANSACTION_TYPE) GROUP BY a.TRANSACTION_TYPE, a.NAME, a.CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD, a.ClassGroup.
```

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: show us your expected output in tabular form.

Comment: Well, just use `COUNT(DISTINCT a.SR_NUM`)?

Comment: Hi @zealous I have added to my initial post. I am able to get the count for Building but based on the SQL i posted, it is restricting the count for 'Trade' completely. I need to count both 'Building' and 'Trade' group, if I have 1 SR NUM for 'Building' and 'Trade' group, then the count should happen only for 'Building' plus count of SR_NUM for 'trade' class should not be available in 'Building' class and should have qunique count in its own. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Hi @gotqn - I did that but its counting 1 for each classes.

Comment: You need to add some sample data in order this to be reproduce easier and solved.

Comment: Hi @gotqn I have added screenshots of the data and the desired output. Please let me know if you are not able to view it. Am new here, so not sure if I missed any info.

Comment: @macvj87 . . . (1) Your query is not syntactically correct and so is hard to follow.  (2) Your description mentions two computed columns but your sample data only has one.  (3) Your sample data may not be complete.  It is not clear if there are multiple rows for the same `sr_num` with "building" or "trade".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count on the fact that MIN between 'Building' and 'Trade' is 'Building' ( in order to 'eliminate' the 'Trade' entry when a 'Building' entry exists)

```
SELECT      a.TRANSACTION_TYPE
            ,a.NAME
            ,a.SR_NUM
            ,a.CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD
            ,MIN(a.ClassGroup) as ClassGroup
FROM        YourTable a
GROUP BY    a.TRANSACTION_TYPE
            ,a.NAME
            ,a.SR_NUM
            ,a.CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD
```

Once you have this is just a matter of wrapping it in a CTE and applying a simple COUNT DISTINCT

```
WITH CTE AS (
            SELECT      a.TRANSACTION_TYPE
                        ,a.NAME
                        ,a.SR_NUM
                        ,a.CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD
                        ,MIN(a.ClassGroup) as ClassGroup
            FROM        YourTable a
            GROUP BY    a.TRANSACTION_TYPE
                        ,a.NAME
                        ,a.SR_NUM
                        ,a.CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD 
            )
SELECT  TRANSACTION_TYPE
        ,NAME
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT SR_NUM) as SR_COUNT
        ,CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD
        ,ClassGroup
FROM CTE
GROUP BY    TRANSACTION_TYPE
            ,NAME
            ,CNTR_SRV_TYPE_CD
            ,ClassGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.transaction_type, t.name, t.contr_srv_type_cd, t.classgroup,
       count(distint sr_num) as num_sr_num,
       sum(case when sr_num = 'Trade' then 1 else 0 end) as num_trades
from t
where t.classgroup = 'Building'
group by t.transaction_type, t.name, t.contr_srv_type_cd, t.classgroup;
```

At least, this seems to do what you are asking and works for the data you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Apologies for not making myself clear. All i wanted was to  eliminate the 'Trade' entry when a 'Building' entry existed.